# Alexa: How to get User request's text message in default fallback intend?

Tags: alexa-skills-kit

I have an utterance like

"what is {my_slot}"

and "my_slot" is having values like Java, Oracle, PHP

Suppose user ask for a question "What is js", which is not in my slot value, Alexa's defaultfallback is triggerd in the above situtaion.

How to get the text message / slot value which is given by the user?

Answer (score 0):

Slot values samples that you provide are treated as training data. So values that are not in your list will also be returned to you.

> When you create a custom slot type, a key concept to understand is
>   that this is training data for Alexa’s NLP (natural language
>   processing). The values you provide are NOT a strict enum or array
>   that limit what the user can say. This has two implications
>
> 1) words and phrases not in your slot values will be passed to you,
>
> 2) your code needs to perform any validation you require if what’s
>   said is unknown.

If your interaction model design is correct, when the users say "What is js" that intent will be triggered and the slot value "js" will be passed to you. You should then validate the slot value and respond back with an appropriate response.

`AMAZON.FallbackIntent` is triggered when there are no appropriate intent mappings for the user utterance.

If your utterance "What is js" is triggering `AMAZON.FallbackIntent`, then update/change your interaction model such that it will map to associated intent and slot correctly. Then validate "js" in your backend.

Comment: This is sadly not true, FallbackIntent, at least now, means Alexa did not recognize the intent at all therefore **didn't recognize the slot in general** - you just don't get anything user said in the Fallback, it's very sad, but that's how it currently works :(